# Pytest: Assert nested mock is called

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I want to make sure the `mkdir` function from the `Path` module is called in a function that I test.

I mock the Path module, when I try asserting the `mkdir` function is called (which is, in the context of the test, a nested mock of the `Path` module mock), it returns `false`.

I made sure that both nested mock are the same object.
What is more surprising, is that even in the tested function context, the nested mock has no calls list

How is that explained, and how can I perform that test ?

**sandbox.py:**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


def create_dir():
    Path(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Dummy")).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  #Path.mkdir => <MagicMock name='Path.mkdir' id='2166014878976'>

    if isinstance(Path, MagicMock):
        assert Path.mock_calls is not []
        assert Path.mkdir.mock_calls is []
```

**test_sandbox.py:**

```
from pathlib import Path
from pytest import fixture

import sandbox
from sandbox import create_dir


@fixture
def mock_path(mocker):
    yield mocker.patch(f"{sandbox.__name__}.{Path.__name__}")


def test_that_creating_directory_calls_mkdir(mock_path):
    create_dir()

    mock_path.assert_called()
    mock_path.mkdir.assert_called()  # mock_path.mkdir => <MagicMock name='Path.mkdir' id='2166014878976'>
```

Comment: You are testing the call on the class instead of the object, you need `mock_path.return_value.mkdir.assert_called()` instead.

Comment: It also work with mock_path().mkdir.assert_called()

Comment: Yes, that's basically the same.